# Definition : addMethodCall works but methods are never invoked

Tags: symfony, service, tags

I want to use custom tags on my services, so I followed the instructions in the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/components/dependency_injection/tags.html

I have a RulesHydrator class:

```
<?php

namespace TestBundle\Thruway;

class RulesHydrator
{
    private $container;
    private $manualChecks = [];

    public function __construct($container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function addManualCheck($service, $rule, $method)
    {
        echo 'addManualCheck invoked!'.PHP_EOL;
        exit;
        $this->manualChecks[$rule] = $service;
    }
}
```

Here is the compiler pass:

```
<?php

namespace TestBundle\Thruway;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class ThruwayCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->has('thruway.rules_hydrator')) {
            return;
        }

        $definition = $container->findDefinition('thruway.rules_hydrator');

        foreach ($container->findTaggedServiceIds('thruway.manual_check') as $id => $tags) {
            foreach ($tags as $attributes) {
                $definition->addMethodCall('addManualCheck', [new Reference($id), $attributes['rule'], $attributes['method']]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my bundle's class:

```
<?php

namespace TestBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use TestBundle\Thruway\ThruwayCompilerPass;

class TestBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->addCompilerPass(new ThruwayCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

My services.yml file look like this:

```
services:
    thruway.rules_hydrator:
        class: TestBundle\Thruway\RulesHydrator

    thruway.customer_checker:
        class: TestBundle\Thruway\MyChecker
        tags:
            - { name: thruway.manual_check, rule: some.rule1, method: someMethod1 }
            - { name: thruway.manual_check, rule: some.rule2, method: someMethod2 }
```

The *process* method is called and the different calls to *addMethodCall* on my **Definition** object work fine (the property "calls" of the definition is correctly filled). The problem is that the calls to my method *addManualCheck* never occur. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The case could be that you did not instantiated the service. By default from what I remember the services are lazy loaded, and until you actually fetch one from the container, or it is injected into an other service, it will not be initialized.

Can you look into your appProdProjectContainer.php inside app/cache/prod for the "TestBundle\Thruway\MyChecker" and post back how it is used?

Also try a fast check by getting the thruway.customer_checker from the container.

A fast command like this could help

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class TestCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('service:test')->setDescription('Test service functionalities');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $service = $this->getContainer()->get('thruway.customer_checker');
    }
}
```